# Not transparent background after inserting png on pdf

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, pdf, imagick

I'm trying to add png image on pdf file using Imagick on Ubuntu Server.

```
$background = imagecolorallocate($signature_place, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($signature_place, 0, 0 , $background);
imagecolortransparent($signature_place, $background);
```

But the background has a dirty white color.

[Example on Ubuntu Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yZTK.png)

The interesting fact that it works correctly on Windows.

[Example on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T781E.jpg)

I'm using:

- php7.0-fpm
- php-imagick 3.4.3

I really don't understand where the error could be.

Did anyone have such problem? Where should I find the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for PNG

```
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($this->source);
    imagealphablending($newImg, false);
    imagesavealpha($newImg, true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($newImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($newImg, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $transparent);
    imagecopyresampled($newImg, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $this->srcWidth, $this->srcHeight);
    imagepng($newImg, $this->destin);
```